# How can I move the objects in a single direction?

Tags: 3d-view

How can I move the objects in a single direction? Im tired of it going off course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the transformation to a single axis.

You can also press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the transformation to two axes. For example, <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will constrain the transformation to the X/Y plane.